# HP Envy Mhz almost always stays at minimum (400HZ) even under heavy load

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance, cpufreq

After using Linux Mint 18.3 for about half a year without issues, I installed Linux Mint 19 in my OS yesterday.
But it seamed a lot more laggy and unresponsive running of the USB Stick. I didn't think much about it, but even after the installation it was still very slow, and had trouble playing a youtube video.
After generating a bit of synthetic load using dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null,
I observed that the CPU speed always sat at 400MHZ with a maximum of 4000.
Sometimes it randomly goes higher than that, mostly at boot, but it seamed very random.
The dual booted windows doesn't have that problem and is signifanntly more responsive.
So I went back to 18.3 and eventually Ubuntu Mate, only to find the same issues again.
I disabled Intel Guard extensions in the bareboenes Bios, but it doesn't change anything.
even maximising this browser window takes up to 10 seconds with nothing else running, no other root or user process is really using the CPUs.
The computer is also unusaully quiet, while the fans are spinning under heavy load with windows.
Does anybody have any idea what could be the issue?

Heres my Screenfetch:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
 Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.15.0-39-generic
 Uptime: 58m
 Packages: 2099
 Shell: bash 4.4.19
 Resolution: 1920x1080
 DE: MATE 1.20.0
 WM: Metacity (Marco)
 GTK Theme: 'Ambiant-MATE' [GTK2/3]
 Icon Theme: Ambiant-MATE
 Font: Ubuntu 11
 CPU: Intel Core i7-8550U @ 8x 1.6GHz [44.0°C]
 GPU: intel
 RAM: 2663MiB / 15797MiB
```

Seams better after downgrade to

```
 OS: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
 Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.15.0-29-generic
 Uptime: 19m
 Packages: 2121
 Shell: bash 4.4.19
 Resolution: 1920x1080
 DE: MATE 1.20.0
 WM: Metacity (Marco)
 GTK Theme: 'Ambiant-MATE' [GTK2/3]
 Icon Theme: Ambiant-MATE
 Font: Ubuntu 11
 CPU: Intel Core i7-8550U @ 8x 4GHz [42.0°C]
 GPU: intel
 RAM: 2327MiB / 15797MiB
```

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: so you think this is Linux' fault?

Comment: No, not linux. Linux is the kernel. If you have no problems under 18.3, then the problem is in 19.

Comment: no Its still slow under 18.3 when I reinstall 18.3

Comment: I dongraded (see post). Now it seams to work ok I think.

Comment: I'll report a bugreport once im sure it actually runs faster